# Is it possible to use attributes when accessing XML nodes using dot-notation?

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath

PowerShell has dot syntax for accessing some XML nodes:

```
root.object1.object2
```

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
root.object1.object2[@id="pdt1"]
```

except this syntax doesn't work.

Does this kind of syntax exist or is it mandatory to use `SelectNodes()` method?

Comment: You can use `Where-Object`: `root.object1.object2|? id -eq pdt1`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can't mix object and XPath syntax like that. Either use XPath:

```
$xml.SelectSingleNode('/root/object1/object2[@id="pdt1"]')
```

or use object syntax with a [`Where-Object`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177028.aspx) filter (as suggested by @PetSerAl in the comments to your question):

```
$xml.root.object1.object2 | Where-Object { $_.id -eq 'pdt1' }
```

Comment: I didn't know about Where-Object thanks. I wish they'll add the more natural syntax in the future.